# Re-enumerate column B contents based on Column A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':[101,101,101,103,103,103,103],
                   'Sub-Category':[0,3,4,0,2,4,5]})

df
  Category Sub-Category
0   101      0
1   101      3
2   101      4
3   103      0
4   103      2
5   103      4
6   103      5
```

But I want to re-enumerate items in `sub-category` based on each corresponding `Category`. So that the final result is:

```
  Category Sub-Category
0   101      1
1   101      2
2   101      3
3   103      1
4   103      2
5   103      3
6   103      4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: enumerate items in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263102/pandas-enumerate-items-in-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with a [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html)

```
df["Sub-Category"] = df.groupby(
    "Category", as_index=False
)["Sub-Category"].cumcount()

# start at 1 instead of 0
df["Sub-Category"] += 1

print(df)

   Category  Sub-Category
0       101             1
1       101             2
2       101             3
3       103             1
4       103             2
5       103             3
6       103             4
```